# Progress of StorageFile.CopyAsync in a Windows 8 Store app

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, async-await, winrt-async

I'm creating a Store app using C# and XAML. I wanted to show the user the progress of file operations such as file copy. The API I'm using is [StorageFile.CopyAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227193.aspx).

It returns a task which is `await`-able. So I can tell my app to wait for the operation to finish. But if the file is too large I won't be able to tell how much of it, the app has copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `CopyAsync` returns [`IAsyncOperation<StorageFile>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206598.aspx) instead of [`IAsyncOperationWithProgress<StorageFile>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206594.aspx), you're out of luck with this API. I don't think there's any built in API for copying that would implement progress reporting ([`Stream.CopyAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh159084.aspx) doesn't implement it either).

You could always implement your own version which copies bytes from one stream to another in chunks and reports progress while doing it. It might be less performant than the built in APIs, though.

Comment: I thought about implementing my own methods but I'm not sure if it can preserve all the properties related to the files in the system (such as modified date).